# Like button Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

On blastmagazine.com our Like button has worked with the same code for a long time, but last week it started giving us an error:

> The app ID specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag is not allowed on
>   this domain. You must setup the Connect Base Domains for your app to
>   be a prefix of
>   http://blastmagazine.com/the-issue/the-top-five-failed-apple-products/.

This is the code we've been using:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=200&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:35px;float:right;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

We also have Facebook comments enabled, but that appears to be working correctly.

Comment: Have you defined a `site url` or `site domain` in the developer app?

Comment: yes, I think so. i never had to use a developer app before. we just pasted the iframe months ago and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

- App ID does not match domain
- Required Property Missing (og:image)

Correct your AppId (check if your App shows in your list) and add og:image meta tagg

Comment: How do I do this? I never used an app id before or an og:image

Comment: I'm not using any appid. I just copied and pasted the iframe from the Facebook website. It always worked before.